# child_added for new items only with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this code below which works (no syntax or any other errors) except that the output of this code displays all the results under `/server/name`:

i.e:

```
We have a new event:
  { des: 'test123', name: 'Test', nice: 'wew' } lol
```

**Here is the Code in functions/index.js:**

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/server/name').onWrite(event => {


 admin.database().ref("/server/name").limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

 console.log('We have a new event:', snapshot.val());


   });
```

**Here is the DB:**

[image]

### **Update 2:**

```
   exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/server/name/{num}').onWrite(event => {

console.log('We have a new event:', event.data.val(), 'lol');
});
```

Output in Logs:

### **Update 3:**

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: What is the function's expected behavior? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JenPerson Send FCM (firbease cloud messaging) of new events added to DB

Comment: Ah I see. I'm trying to understand the purpose of the listener inside the function. Why not use event.data.val() to get the data of the new event?

Comment: @JenPerson `event.data.val()` returns all data too. I don't know how to modify `functions.database.ref('/server/name').onWrite` to return new elements only

Comment: ok so you don't want to return the value of "1", but the value of one of those test strings? Like just "Test" or "cool"? If so, I have the solution

Comment: @JenPerson, exactly, I need the newest word. in this case "cool". slightly off-topic: the purpose of 1 is that I have multiple url links. 1st link gets JSON of Facebook events from 1st page. Thus number `1` and if other FB pages also have events. it saves the names of the events under `2`, `3`, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the trigger is attached higher in the path than you want.

Instead,if you're planning on having multiple lists of events to listen to and this is just list 1 of many, use a wildcard:

```
exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref('/server/name/{num}/{notification}').onWrite(event => {
    ...
})
```

You can choose wildcard names that better fit your specific code.

Comment: Thank you for the help Jen, However, according to logs `events.data` still outputs all values. I updated my question with a picture

Comment: it does work, but because you are labeling your keys '1, 2, 3...' Firebase interprets this as an array and therefore shows an array. If you use different keys, it works. I tried it myself just now.

Comment: that's weird, can you post the whole code ? Maybe because I'm not returning a promise or something ? Here is the log after modifiying the DB http://i.imgur.com/u5K2UM1.png & http://i.imgur.com/9G8URDE.png

Comment: @Suhaib update your question to reflect what your code looks like now.

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer and I tested it to make sure it works as expected. I realize I had to go even deeper into the path.

Comment: you are amazing + awesome. Thank you